# JS chaining functions

Tags: javascript, chaining

I'm writing a function that should work like this:

```
checker(3).equals(3) // true
checker(3).not().equals(3) // false
checker(3).not().equals(4) // true
checker(3).not().not().equals(4) // false
```

The code I came up with:

```
function checker(num) {
  let number = num
  return {
    not() {
      number = !number
      return this
    },
    equals(nmb) {
      return number === nmb
    }
  }
}
```

I can't wrap my head around what should `not()` do so as to make `checker(num)` work as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another boolean property that changes how `equals` works depending on it's value.

```js
function checker(num) {
  let number = num
  let not = false
  return {
    not() {
      not = !not
      return this
    },
    equals(nmb) {
      return not ? number !== nmb : number === nmb
    }
  }
}

console.log(checker(3).equals(3)) // true
console.log(checker(3).not().equals(3)) // false
console.log(checker(3).not().equals(4)) // true
console.log(checker(3).not().not().equals(4)) // false
```

Comment: You could replace `not ? number !== nmb : number === nmb` with `(number === nmb) !== not`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe somthing like this:

```
function checker(num) {
  let number = num
  let beTrue = true;
  return {
    not() {
      beTrue = !beTrue;
      return this
    },
    equals(nmb) {
      return (number === nmb) === beTrue;
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to fullfil your requirements. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 [approach](https://jsfiddle.net/6hxLs9af/)

```
const checker=(number, negate)=>{
    const neg = negate || false;
  return {
    not(){
        return checker(number, !neg);
    }, 
    equals(number2){
        if (neg) return number != number2;
      return number == number2;
    }
  }
}
```

> what should not() do so as to make checker(num) work as it is supposed to.

not could return a new checker.

Answer (score 1):

I think i would let the `not`function control the operator, something like

```
function checker(num) {
  let operator = 'equals'; 
  let number = num
  return {
    not() {
      if(operator==='equals')    
         operator = 'not equals'; 
      else 
          operator = 'equals'; 
      return this
    },
    equals(nmb) {
      if(operator==='equals')  
         return number === nmb
      else 
        return number !== nmb
    }
  }
}
```

just using a string as operator for clarity, a proberly better solution could be to use a boolean or number value